# iOS: Build a Resource Bundle via Xcode Target

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, target

I want to create a Resource Bundle from resource files of my static library via a xcode target. I saw Three20 having a .bundle file one need to import.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 18):

## Important Disclaimer:

Apple does not endorse this solution. When I spoke with a developer at Apple who works on Xcode they informed me that resource bundles were **not supported** by iOS, and they were surprised that this worked at all.

This solution has worked for me on iOS 9 through 13, both phone and tablet. However it's possible that a future update to iOS may break this. Just be aware of that.

## Now on to the answer:

I know it's 8 years late, but since I stumbled across this question there's a good chance someone else will, so I thought I'd provide a helpful answer.

### Step 1. Create a new Target

[image]

- Make sure you have your project selected in the **Project Navigator**
- Click on the `+` at the bottom of the Targets list

### Step 2. Create a macOS Bundle

[image]

We'll convert this to an iOS Bundle in step 3

### Step 2 (cont). Create a macOS Bundle

[image]

- Name your bundle
- Click "Finish"

### Step 3. Change the Base SDK from macOS to iOS

[image]

- Make sure you have the new resource bundle target selected
- Go to **Build Settings**
- Look for `Base SDK` and change this value from `macOS` to `iOS`

At this point, you're technically done with your question (creating a Resource Bundle target for iOS), but there's some configuration needed to get it working correctly

### Step 4. Replace iOS Bundle Resources

[image]

- Make sure you have your app target selected (**not** the resource bundle)
- Go to **Build Phases**
- Select all resources
- Press the `-` button to remove them

### Step 4 (cont). Replace iOS Bundle Resources

[image]

- Press the `+` button to add a new bundle resource to the iOS app (not pictured)
- Select your bundle product
- Click "Add"

### Step 5. Set up Dependencies

[image]

- Open the **Dependencies** section (still under Build Phases and still within your app, not the resource bundle)
- Click the `+` button to add a new dependency

### Step 5 (cont). Set up Dependencies

[image]

- Select the resource bundle project
- Click "Add"

## Now you're done!

With all of those steps completed, you will be building a resource bundle compatible with iOS and embedding it inside of your application to be loaded. It's not as straight-forward and a lot of articles may say this is unsupported, but I've used this feature in a published app and it works perfectly

Just remember that if you want to add any resources to your app now (PNGs, XIB files, etc) you need to add them to **the bundle** and not the app, like so:

[image]

## Important Gotcha

After you've set this up, check out your resource bundle's build settings one more time. Look for the setting titled "Versioning System". This value **must be** set to `None`. If this is set to `Apple Generic`, you **will** run into issues when you try to push to the app store!

Apple's versioning system will create a `*_vers.c` file, compile it, and embed this binary into your bundle. As this is not a valid CFBundleExecutable, it will cause your app to be rejected with error ITMS-90171

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Your Hint on Versioning System saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Can you explain why you say this is unsupported? 

The [current documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle) doesn't mention anything about these being unsupported on iOS, and is even tagged with `iOS 2.0+`, and the [Apple bundle programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i) guide starts with the text `Bundles are a fundamental technology in macOS and iOS...`.

Comment: @TonyLovesDevOps I don’t generally do iOS dev (I picked it up for a month for a job) and this was 2 years ago, but as best as I can remember: iOS normally creates a single bundle implicitly, but creating a separate bundle target is not supported. The method even involves creating a MacOS bundle and tricking it into working on iOS. Apple provides premium developer support for a fee, and it was through this channel (paying money to talk to their engineers) that I was told it was not supported.

Answer (score 7):

A bundle is just a directory with a special structure and a .bundle extension.  You can read more about the specifics in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html).

**Edit:**

The important part is that a bundle is just a normal folder named with a special extension.  For instance, if you had a folder named MyBundle.bundle and an image inside named image.png, you can load it with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBundle.bundle/image.png"];`  Thus, there's no need to build it via an Xcode target.  In fact, it's not available on iOS projects. You could have a Copy Files build phase in your project, or a shell script.

This is simple, and powerful.  For example, if you conform to the special structure listed at the docs for frameworks, you can build static libs into Frameworks using a simple method, shell scripts or ant tasks or rake files.  As long as the output directory conforms to the structure and is named Something.framework, you can use it as a Framework, even on iOS.

Comment: The documentation does NOT provide that info - it's vague and hand-waving and ignores the actual question. I came here from Google specificlaly BECAUSE I'd read the docs you link to, and while they work for OS X, most of the iOS details are missing. Downvoting.

Comment: @Adam, hopefully I've provided more detail behind my thoughts and reason for linking to the docs.