# In my own SDK, how do I play a mp3 of this SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, bundle

I use swift to write the SDK myself. There is an mp3 file in the SDK, and I want to play the mp3 in the SDK. I realized that it is no longer possible to use:

```
Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sound_tap", withExtension: "mp3")
```

On the following sites I found it seems to work:

```
Bundle.module.url(forResource: "sound_tap", withExtension: "mp3")
```

[apple developer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/bundling-resources-with-a-swift-package)

But:

> "Bundle.module" cannot be used because "Type 'Bundle' has no member
> 'module'".

So how do I play the mp3 of this SDK in my own SDK?
Thanks for any help.

Swift 5, iOS11

Comment: Have you read that article completely? Especially the paragraph **Explicitly declare or exclude resources**?

Comment: @burnsi To be honest, my English is not very good, so I didn't fully understand it. Is the part you said the solution? I will read it again carefully. thanks

Comment: Well i don´t know if that is the solution. But it describes steps how to add a resource and how the `module` code is created by xcode, if you do it properly. If you haven´t read/understood that, that may be the reason this is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Bundle target for files like video, images or xib, then link your mp3 file to this bundle target.

[How to create a bundle target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59198079/4323941)

**Use following code to access the file:**

```
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YOUR-BUNDLE-NAME", ofType: "bundle")
let bundle = Bundle(path: bundlePath)
let filePath = bundle.path(forResource: "YOUR-FILE-NAME", ofType:"mp3")
```

**Play video file:**

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
....
player.play()
```

Comment: Thanks, after I have completed the above steps, the following code still does not return the bundlePath correctly:
<let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YOUR-BUNDLE-NAME", ofType: "bundle")>

Comment: Did you create bundle target? if so, please send a screenshot of project targets and exact code to check error.

Comment: I realized that there is no SDK Bundle in my app, maybe I used the SDK in a non-standard way. Then, I added my own SDK "SDK-NAME.framework" in the "Copy Bundle Resources" of the target App. Then use:
let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "YOUR-SDK-NAME", ofType: "framework")
Then you can use it.
Your answer still expands my train of thought, thank you very much.